# c# FromStream(stream) invalid parameter?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

First the method preEntities() inserts a new record into the Entities table. One of the inserted values is an image. The data type for this column in the visual studio database is 'image'.

The method loadPanel() is supposed to take the image from every single record in the table (WHERE TYPE = OBSTACLE) and make a picturebox with that image. However there is an error in the FromStream() method: "INVALID PARAMETER"; I put a comment where the error showed up. I searched for previously asked questions about this error but I didn't find anything yet that helped me :(

```
    private void preEntities() {
        string constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="
             + "|DataDirectory|\\DonaldJump.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        byte[] image = ImageToByteArray(Properties.Resources.Pipe);
        string q = "INSERT INTO dbo.Entities(Name, Type, Image, Width, Height) VALUES('Pipe','Obstacle','" + image + "','97','150')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn) {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

     private void loadPanel() {
        string constring = "Data Source (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="
             + "|DataDirectory|\\DonaldJump.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        string q = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Entities WHERE Type='obstacle';";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(q, con)) {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                dt.Load(dr);
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Location = new Point(10, 10); 
            pb.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            byte[] img = dr.Field<byte[]>("Image");
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(img);
            pb.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream); //ERROR IS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            pb.Name = dr.Field<string>("Name");
            pb.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;
            pb.Click += pbClick;
            pb.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to save the stream into a file and open it with an image viewer?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Comment: Just `File.WriteAllBytes("path", img);`. But the real issue is in the saving part.

Comment: My biggest concern is...... you are not disposing the stream and using it again in a loop.... Suggest you to use "using" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate a string with a byte array. The result will be something like `'Pipe','Obstacle','System.Byte[]','97','150'`.

You need to use SqlParameter.
First create the query and then add parameters to your command :

```
string q = "INSERT INTO dbo.Entities(Name, Type, Image, Width, Height) VALUES('Pipe','Obstacle',@image,'97','150')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", img);
```

Comment: Thanks that helped alot!